# using vue and axios to post to .net web api using nullable properties

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api, axios

Here is a very simplified scenario of what I need to do. In the web api I have controller with a Get and Post where I am using the same object for both.

```c#
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("GetTestingData")]
    public JsonResult GetTestingData()
    {
        return Json(new TestingData());
    }

    [HttpPost("PostTestingData")]
    public JsonResult PostTestingData(TestingData testingData)
    {
        return Json("");
    }
}

public class TestingData { 
    public decimal? SomeNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in my vue page I have an onBeforeMount where I am going to get the data for the page and bind it to a variable, in this case testData. I then use this to bind to the v-model on the page for the input.

```html
<template>
    <input v-model="testData.someNumber" />
    <button type="button" @click="submitSomeNumber">Submit</button>
</template>

 
<script> 
   import { onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue"
   import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        setup() {

            let testData = ref({});

            onBeforeMount(() => {
                axios.get('/api/Test/GetTestingData').then(response => {
                    testData.value = response.data;
                });
            });

            const submitSomeNumber = () => {
                axios.post('/api/Test/PostTestingData', testData.value).then(response => { });
            }

            return { testData, submitSomeNumber }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem I am running into is, if I don't provide a value in testData.someNumber when I submit I get a 400 error - bad request. I am assuming this is because an empty string is not matching up to a nullable decimal. Is there something I can add to the startup.cs in my api to convert an empty value to null so it can serialize the json to the object? I need to be able to submit this without providing a value here.

Comment: Axios puts the response data into the `data` property. Use `testData.value = response.data;`

Comment: Yep you're right, I missed that one. The issue still remains that I need to be able submit the form without providing a value.

Comment: What is the actual text for the 400 response? You can use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to check it as well as the request data that is being made